# How to open a new window by using GridView On RowCommand Event?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp GridView from where, I am using RowCommand and take some value from this page to another page and I want to open that page on to new window.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.CommandName == "Trans")
   {
       Response.Redirect("APIwiserecharge.aspx?
       DisplayID="objdl.Encode(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));
   }
}
```

and at the .aspx page i m using this.

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="APIDetails" ItemStyle-Width="200px">
              <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="trans" runat="server"CommandName="TransText="Details" 
              CommandArgument = '<%#Eval("DisplayID") %>'> 
               </asp:LinkButton>
             </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Trans")
    {
        Response.Write("<script>window.open('APIwiserecharge.aspx?DisplayID=' + objdl.Encode(e.CommandArgument.ToString()) ,'_blank');</script>");
        //OR
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow1", "window.open('APIwiserecharge.aspx?DisplayID=" + objdl.Encode(e.CommandArgument.ToString()) + "');",true);
        //OR
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "OpenWindow1", "window.open('APIwiserecharge.aspx?DisplayID=" + objdl.Encode(e.CommandArgument.ToString()) + "');", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir its not working.For this upto now i am not add anything at aspx page.So please give me varified code thanks..

Comment: yes sir, still its not working.I Havenot add any modelpopup extender at aspx page.